Probabilistic Turing Machine and Cryptography
Lecture notes I am reading says:

An issue with characterizing efficiency in terms of P is that the
feasibility of a problem is thus considered in terms of its worst-case
complexity only. For cryptographic and for cryptanalytic purposes,
however, it is much more relevant to consider average-case complexity
instead. The critical notion is that of a probabilistic Turing
machine, which behaves similarly to a nondeterministic Turing machine,
except that on each step it chooses the successor configuration
uniformly at random from the possible ones

Now it is recently, that I tried to understand the concept of non-deterministic Turing machine, and on the surface level I'd say I understand it. For example if there is some value on the current tape and it is in certain state next move could be:

Write a Y, move right, and switch to state 5 or
Write an X, move left, and stay in state 3.

As I understand probabilistic Turing machine is also non deterministic Turing machine but would choose from (1) or (2) with 50/50.
What I don't understand in above quote, is why is cryptography more interested in probabilistic Turing machines? Why is that more useful for cryptography than say deterministic Turing machines? Why does that reflect the average case complexity as in the quote? Examples would be appreciated, say example of a adversary which is implemented as a probabilistic Turing machine.

"Now it is recently that I tried to understand the concept of non deterministic Turing machine, and on the surface level I'd say I understand it." - I don't think you do. For a nondeterministic turing machine, what it does is magically pick the option that leads to "success", somehow knowing which that would be. Another way of looking at it is that it takes both options (logically splitting the state), and then when some fork reaches a state marked "success", the whole thing claims success. This obviously can't be implemented directly on real computers without an exponential slowdown.

I don't think I'd say it's obvious it's exponential @poncho, considering there's a million dollar prize nobody has claimed for proving it can't be done for polynomial time problems on NTMs. Besides, PTMs are a different beast from NTMs, and it's usually thought that BPP = P in the same way it's usually thought P ≠ NP.

@timuzhti: it's obvious that the straight-forward implementation (forking every time you hit a nondeterministic branch) takes exponential time - I never said there weren't more efficient approaches

It seems your question has been answered elsewhere [you linked]. If not, you need to clarify why it's not answered there

Anyway, I would expect there aren't really any crypto based on such problems, but "Why are only lattice problems used in cryptography?", for example, mentions (with a citation) that 3SAT is easy with high probability.

@timuzhti: it is common that a random instance of a class of problems is easy, but that it's easy to define a less large subclass where a random instance is hard. Or vice versa. The sampling method might also matter. The reference you indirectly link to is about the subclass "planted 3SAT", whatever that is.
